# How to pause and send signal from one process to other in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

New to python so this might sound like a basic question. I have a new process spawn off the main process to do something in parallel with the main process. *I cannot use threads in this specific case cause of some underlining APIs threading issues*. I am trying to achieve some synchronization among both the processes. I read about [signals](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) but I couldn't find a proper example which aligns with my case. Some example code:

```
import multiprocessing
import signal
def process_one(self):
    # Do something
    second_process = Process(target=self.process_two)
    second_process.start()
    # Do something and send signal to process_two to unpause
    # Do other things
    second_process.join()

def process_two(self):
    # Do something
    # Now I want to pause this process till I receive a signal from
    # process_one
    signal.pause()
    # continue to do other things
```

As I have mentioned in the comments, I am trying to figure out a way to achieve this. Most of the examples I saw were for `forks`. Pointers?

Comment: Your code seems like a good start. Are you having trouble getting it to worK?

Comment: @univerio Yes! Am not sure what kind of signal to define and send to `process_two`. All I saw was that there is an `os.kill()` that sends a signal to another process but that's not what I want.

Comment: [`signal(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) defines a list of signals. In particular, `SIGCONT` seems an appropriate signal. Why is `os.kill()` not what you want?

Comment: Oh! I missed it in my code. After `second_process.join()` I need to do some other stuff before `process_one` dies. So wouldn't `os.kill()` kill the main process before it completes?

Comment: `kill` is a misnomer. [`kill(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill) is used to send a signal to a process. One of the signals you can send happens to be `SIGKILL`, which kills the process. So, no, it won't kill `process_one` if you don't send it a `SIGKILL`.

Comment: Rather than using signals, you might find more mileage in the `multiprocessing` package's built in synchronisation tools: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes. If process 1 locks a `Lock`, then process 2 can block on that when appropriate. Process 1 can then unlock it as the 'signal'. If you need more sophisticated communication, then a queue is a fairly easy next step.

Answer (score 4):

Solved it using [Event()](https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html#signaling-between-processes)

The example posted there was exactly what I wanted.