# How can one break a loop in a process from another process?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to break a loop in a process while it's being monitored by another process.

example code:

```
loop1 = True
loop2 = True

def function1():
    while loop1:
        #do something
    else:
        loop1

def function2():
    while loop2:
        if something == True:
            #break loop1
            break
        else:
            loop2

def main():
    process1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=function1)
    process2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=function2)
    process1.start()
    process2.start()
    process1.join()
    process2.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Questions:

- How can i break loop in function1() from function2()?
- If i break out from the loop will it mean that process finished it's task and will join?
- is the "**name** == '**main**':" really necessary or are there other ways to call processess?
- If every process joins will it terminate itself and then start over again or will it just continue? If so, then how can i terminate and start over?

Comment: This is more than one question. Other users of stackoverflow will find this question by the title, and the other embedded questions are likely not to be a fit for what they're looking for. Consider asking each question separately.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Broadcast message to multiple Multiprocessing processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72241802/broadcast-message-to-multiple-multiprocessing-processes) also [How to pause and send signal from one process to other in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35005037/how-to-pause-and-send-signal-from-one-process-to-other-in-python)

Comment: Another way to invoke a python function is to create another module that just invokes that function. That sounds odd, but if you create such a module and name it `__main__.py`, then `python -m package` will invoke your function. Another way to invoke a python function is to refer to it from an [entrypoint specification](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/entry-points/) and install the package.

Comment: You could use `signal` library

Answer (score 0):

To break from function1 in function2 in separate processes, you'd need to use some kind of inter-process communication. An obvious solution would be to use a sentry file.

```py
from pathlib import Path


sentry_file = Path('sentry_file').touch(exist_ok=True)

def function1():
    while sentry_file.exists():
        #do something
    else:
        loop1

def function2():
    while loop2:
        if condition:
            sentry_file.unlink()
            #break loop1
            break
        else:
            loop2
```

If this is intended for practical use, I'd suggest using a more secure filename than 'sentry_file', or some other kind of IPC. (For more information on creating secure filenames, refer to the [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) module.)

Comment: The [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module has several options that can be used for this, no need to create a file. Examples: `Event`, `Pipe`, `Value`.